# logback.xml not found when running spring framework + maven

Tags: java, spring

I'm currently forced to supply the logback.xml path when executing my maven spring project as follows:

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dlogging.config=src/resources/logback.xml
```

I was expecting the file to be found without having to supply the path. Where do I have to place the file for it to be found when executing the following:

```
mvn spring-boot:run
```

Comment: is logback not found an Exception or just a log statement?

Comment: `src/resources` is not on the classpath, unless specifically add it.  You need to use `src/main/resources`.

Comment: drat ... can't believe I didn't spot that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right location of logback.xml is src/main/resources